# What is the shortcut for rearrange code in Elipse?

Tags: eclipse

In IntelliJ there is a command earrange Code which moves variables to the top of a class and methods afterwards.

Is there a similar shortcut for eclipse ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ***Sort Members*** command has no shortcut by default.

You can either execute the command **via Quick Access** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> and entering `Sort Members`) **or add a shortcut** binding in *Window > Preferences: Generals > Keys*.

You can also add a so-called ***Save Action*** so that the *Sort Members* is automatically executed when saving: in *Project > Properties: Java Editor > Save Actions* enable *Additional actions*, click *Configure...* and in the tab *Code Organizing* enable *Sort members*.